# MPI_Exchanging sides of vector between processes

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

In my code I have an arbitrary number of processes exchanging some parts of their local vectors. The local vectors are vectors of pairs and for this reason I've been using an MPI derived datatype. In principle I don't know how many elements each process sends to the others and for this reason I also have to send the size of the buffer. In particular, each process exchanges data with the process with rank: myrank-1 and with the process with rank: myrank+1. In case of process 0 instead of myrank-1 it exchanges with process with rank comm_size-1. And as well in case of process comm_size-1 instead of myrank+1 it exchanges with process with rank 0.
This is my code:

```
unsigned int size1tobesent;

size1tobesent=last.size();//Buffer size
int slpartner = (rank + 1) % p;
int rlpartner = (rank - 1 + p) % p;
unsigned int sizereceived1;

MPI_Sendrecv(&size1tobesent, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, slpartner, 0,&sizereceived1,1, 
MPI_UNSIGNED, rlpartner, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

Vect first1(sizereceived1);

MPI_Sendrecv(&last[0], last.size(), mytype, slpartner, 0,&first1[0],sizereceived1,    
mytype, rlpartner, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

unsigned int size2tobesent;

size2tobesent=first.size();//Buffer size2

unsigned int sizereceived2;

MPI_Sendrecv(&size2tobesent, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, rlpartner, 0,
&sizereceived2,1,MPI_UNSIGNED, slpartner, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

Vect last1(sizereceived2);
MPI_Sendrecv(&first[0], first.size(), mytype, rlpartner, 0,&last1[0],
sizereceived2 ,mytype, slpartner, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Now when I run my code with 2 or 3 processes all works as expected. With more than 3 the results are unpredictable. I don't know if this is due to a particular combination of the  input data or if there are some theoretical errors that I'm missing. 
Finally consider that this code is part of a for cycle.

Comment: In order to help you, we'd need to see more complete code. Please don't copy all of your code in here though. You should construct a Minimum Working Example (http://sscce.org/) and provide that. Then we'd be able to help you out.

Comment: Well I undestand your corncern but the thing is that the code is  long so I will explain you here how it works.
I'm trying to implement a parallel version of the game of life. My algorithm works with a c++ set of pairs (ordered)  containing the alive individuals. The root scatters this set to the processes. Then the processes exchange just some elements of their local sets between them with that code. The exchange applies to their elements inside their first and last two rows. The algorithhm can then continue. I'm not sure if just this part of code works in general for any number of processes.

Comment: The problem isn't that I don't understand your code, it's that there's probably a mistake somewhere that you aren't spotting. In order to fix it, I would need to see the code. The problem (as you stated) is that your code is long. That's why I asked for a minimum working example. Usually when you do that, you either see the problem as you're minimizing or it becomes much easier to get help.